# Creating a console adapter for an ACME packet server

Tags: serial-port

I am having a hard time with this problem and hoping that someone can help me out. I have an ACME packet 4250 server that needs a console cable to access it. The box itself takes an RJ-45 in the front. Then you use a RS232 to RJ45 to connect it to your computer's serial port. Basically just like a Cisco router. The issue I am running into is the pinout of the terminal adapter does not appear to be standard.

According to Orcale (they own ACME now) they said the pin out should be this;

- Pin 3 --> Receive Data
- Pin 4 --> Transit Data
- Pin 6 --> GND

When I hook up my terminal adapter in (what I think is) the right pinout I get no response from the serial port. It's stone cold dead.

I think the issue is my mis-understanding of how the adapter should be wired up.
The only way I have tried to wire the adapter up is in a straight-through configuration from RJ45 to RS232, pin for pin.

Is there something I am missing? Do I need to cross pins or something?

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I found the manual to the server on Oracle's website. I have included the snippet of documentation that I was referencing.

[image]

Comment: You might have it wired right, but might not have the baud/flow setup correctly. If you don't have the right rates/etc. you won't get a proper sync across the wire (signals won't sync up) and thus it will seem as though nothing is coming through (i.e. a dead/miswired cable) ... Can you get the baud/flow/etc. needed to serial in?

Comment: according to the documentation, it's 9600bps 8N1. No flow control.

Comment: Hi the Baud Rate is 115200 bps (8 data, 1 stop, no parity, no flow control)

Comment: From [cello](http://superuser.com/users/537212/cello): the Baud Rate is 115200 bps (8 data, 1 stop, no parity, no flow control)

Answer (score 1):

Manufacturing cable with the following configuration and works fine for me.

**Pin Assignments: Customer Side**

The following table identifies the pin assignments, color codes, and signal names/descriptions for the DigiKey RJ45 DB9 console connector adaptor in comparison to the RS232/RJ45 connector.

```
                    RJ45 Pin Number         DB9 Pin Number            Color

Receive Data (RXD)  6 --------------------- 2                         Yellow

Transmit Data (TXD) 3 --------------------- 3                         Black

Ground              4 --------------------- 5                         Red
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a "Blue" Cisco console cable with a Null Modem Adapter DB9M/DB9F Modem Gender Changer.  Search sites like Amazon or CDW for "null modem adapter db9f db9m"
the Baud Rate is 115200 bps (8 data, 1 stop, no parity, no flow control)

Comment: Forgot to add that I connect the Cisco cable w/null modem adapter to my USB to Serial cable and I use Putty to connect.